# Determine the equation for the tangent in a point on a curve

Tags: derivatives

I am supposed to determine the equation for the tangent in point (4,1) to the curve:

$$5\sqrt{x}=2\sqrt{y}(x+y^2)$$

I think that I should differentiate the expression and then put the values (4,1) where x and y are. But how do I differentiate this right when both x and y are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can differentiate RHS as the following :
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}(2\sqrt y\ (x+y^2))&=\left(\frac{d}{dx}(2\sqrt y)\right)(x+y^2)+2\sqrt y\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x+y^2)\right)\\&=\left(\frac{d(2\sqrt y)}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)(x+y^2)+2\sqrt y\ \left(1+\frac{d(y^2)}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\\&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt y}\cdot y'\right)(x+y^2)+2\sqrt y\ (1+2yy').\end{align}$$

So, since you'll have
$$\frac{5}{2\sqrt x}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt y}\cdot y'\right)(x+y^2)+2\sqrt y\ (1+2yy'),$$
you'll have the following to solove for $y'$ :
$$\frac{5}{2\sqrt 4}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 1}\cdot y'\right)(4+1^2)+2\sqrt 1\ (1+2\cdot 1\cdot y').$$
The answer will be $y-1=y'(x-4)$.

Comment: I got the same expression as your last expression, but how do I "solve for y'"?

Comment: @theva: LHS$=5/4$ and RHS$=5y'+2(1+2y')=5y'+2+4y'=9y'+2$. So, you'll have $5/4=9y'+2$.

Comment: @theva: Isn't my comment helpful?

Comment: yes it was! I am just tired...

Comment: And how do you go from 5/4=9y'+2 to y-1=y'(x-4)?

Comment: @theva: Since $5/4=9y'+2\Rightarrow 9y'=(5/4)-2=-3/4$, you'll get $y'=-3/(9*4)=-1/12$. So, since $y-1=y'(x-4)$, we have $y-1=(-1/12)(x-4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use implicit differentiation, let's define $F(x,y)$ as follows:
$$F(x,y)=5\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{y}x-2\sqrt{y}y^2$$
We know from implicit differentiation that 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =  -\frac {F_x}{F_y}.$$ So by calculating $-\frac {F_x}{F_y}$ we obtain 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{(5-4\sqrt{xy})\sqrt{y}}{2\sqrt{x}(x+5y^2)}$$
Plugging the point $(4,1)$ at $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we find the slope of tangent line as $-1/12$.
Finally the equation of the tangent line is
$$y-1=-\frac{1}{12}(x-4)$$